# Can't redirect to category list url - django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I can't figure out how can I redirect to category list page but url is working fine i just can't add correct redirect url by id into href tag :(

**html**

```
<div class="widget widget-catgs">
  <h3 class="widget-title">Categories</h3>
  <ul>

    {% for cat in category %}
    <li>
      <a href="**{% url 'category-list' property.category.id %}**" title=""><i
          class="la la-angle-right"></i><span>{{ cat.category__title }}</span></a>
      <span>{{ cat.category__title__count }}</span>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}

  </ul>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def property_by_category(request, category_id):
    property_list = Property.objects.all()
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)
    category_list = Property.objects.filter(category=category)

    context = {
        'category_list': category_list,
        'category_name': category,
        'property': property_list
    }
    return render(request, 'property/property-category.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.property, name='property-page'),
    path('details/<int:property_id>', views.property_details, name='property-details'),
    path('category/<int:category_id>', views.property_by_category, name='category-list'),
    path('add-property/', views.add_property, name='add-property'),
]
```

I'm learning django, please take a look at my code.

Comment: Perhaps you should start with reorganizing your url pattern list and renaming your views. View `property_by_category` named as `category-list` and filtered by `<int:category_id>`? No idea what was your intent. So is this supposed to be a list of categories or a category details page?

Comment: yes i want to show the property list by categories, actually URL is working fine, but I can't find out how to use the url correctly in href, what do you think? I've tried category.id, because in my models.py field name is category (many to many field).